# How to correctly set encoding in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I built an app, I add articles, I view articles, everything is fine on that side of things.

However, I've been setting up sending the articles via email and I came up against encoding issues.  In particular the £ character, it would always create an error.

My database is set to UTF-8 Unicode and my Rails app has `config.encoding = "utf-8"` set.

However, I discovered this:

```
> Article.first.title.encoding.name
=> "ASCII-8BIT"
```

In the end I did a workaround to the get the emails to work (`article.title.force_encoding("utf-8").gsub(/\xC2\xA3/, "£")`) but it feels a bit like a hack to me.

Is there something I've missed?  Some other setting I haven't taken into account?  How do I set up encoding in Rails 3 correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding these articles yourself (i.e. they're not coming from somewhere else, like a scraper), and you're getting this error, it sounds like your browser is sending the wrong encoding to the app. Try adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the `<head>` of your document.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I completely forgot I posted this.  Unfortunately, I've already got the meta charset set.